# Seek bar over an image with border radius

Tags: html, css

I want to set a seek bar over an image like below attached image, tried some trick but it's not working properly.

**I am facing difficulties to set seek bar with border-radius which over the image**

[image]

```css
.img-border-rad {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.progressbar {
  background-color: #b1b1b1;
}

.progressbar>div {
  background-color: #fa1212;
  height: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-pad">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x100" class="img-border-rad">
  <div class="progressbar">
    <div style="width: 40%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a wrapper around both elements and set the border radius on that. Hide overflow on the wrapper.

```css
.border-rad {
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progressbar {
  background-color: #b1b1b1;
}

.progressbar>div {
  background-color: #fa1212;
  height: 4px;
}

img {
  display: block; /* eliminates descender space below */
  max-width: 100%; /* demo only */
}
```

```html
<div class="img-pad border-rad">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x100">

  <div class="progressbar">
    <div style="width: 40%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

isherwood has a more clear answer for the code you presented. However, I still wanted to offer my answer as it is another approach to the same problem. In the code below, I remove the img tag entirely, and render the image as the background of the container. Then I apply the styling to define width, height, border radius, on the container. This way, the progress bar is laid over the image instead of sitting under it.

```css
#test-image-container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background-image: url("https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progressbar { 
  background-color: #b1b1b1; 
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.progressbar > div { 
  background-color: #fa1212; 
  height: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="img-pad" id="test-image-container">
    <div class="progressbar">
      <div style="width: 40%;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks good, but why is it preferable to obscure part of the image?

Comment: On youtube when they offer the progress bar, information about the video, or video controls they will have the info displayed over the video with a somewhat transparent bar. This way screen real estate is not wasted, and aspect ratio of thumbnails maintains integrity. It doesn't make a huge difference for images where it can just be adjusted, however if I intended to have a preview eventually that plays small clip, I would want on hover to make the progress bar completely transparent. Also can just be a design choice.

Comment: Yep, but they also can be hidden (and are automatically hidden). I'm not sure that's relevant here.

Comment: Yes, in this situation it does not make a difference to hide screen or not, it is a more direct and clear solution that you have offered in response to the question. I think my answer may be valuable to others that find this answer with a similar question. There are also ways to have the progress cover img without chaining it to background img, however I often find it easier to work with images as background.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small improvement on @isherwood 's answer, that makes the progress bar div not extend farther right than the image.

Changes: position and display on .border-rad and .progressbar.

EDIT: What the previous answer looks in Chrome when I run it full screen: [image]

```css
.border-rad {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}

.progressbar {
  background-color: #b1b1b1;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.progressbar>div {
  background-color: #fa1212;
  height: 4px;
}

img {
  display: block; /* eliminates descender space below */
  max-width: 100%; /* demo only */
}
```

```html
<div class="img-pad border-rad">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x100">

  <div class="progressbar">
    <div style="width: 40%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The bar _doesn't_ extend past the image in my example. At least not in Chrome.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of what it looks like in Chrome when I run the snipped in full screen. Wonder why this does not happend on your end.

Comment: Oh, the issue there is just that the image is too small. Both are still constrained by the container. Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is using position absolute to position the progress bar to the bottom of the img-pad container, and to set img-pad to display inline-block.

```css
.img-pad {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.img-border-rad {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.progressbar {
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #b1b1b1;
}

.progressbar__done {
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fa1212;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-pad">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dd7c1fa96edde079ae4b987eec68f6d1?s=420&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" class="img-border-rad">
  <div class="progressbar">
    <div class="progressbar__done" style="width:40%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Display inline-block set the div width to fit the content.
Position absolute lets the div be positioned using top, left, right, bottom properties inside the last element that has a position defined.

Checkout these links for more info:

- [MDN Docs - Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)
- [MDN Docs - Display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Check out this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wsc13gjf/